# How can I use node-fhir-server-core in web app with local storage?

Tags: node-fhir-server-core

I'm working on a patient record web app, but I want to allow the user to store the information on their pc/mobile device until they decide to push it to a server.  I looked at node-fhir-server-core, but it is not clear if a web page's localstorage could be 'plugged-in' to the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

So roughly your patient record app is made up of 2 parts, the server which is a central store for all your patient's data and the app which runs on the patient's pc or phone.

Now the [node fhir server](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core) being one part of your solution is separate to your web app's pages. Your web app's pages act as a client to the node fhir server and in these pages you will have to implement the localstorage solution to store the requests/data until such a time a user wants to send them to the node fhir server.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  But the question was can I use the node_fhir_server on the client and configure it to use localstorage?  Although your answer do not directly address that, I'm going to assume the answer is no.

Comment: Okay yes, I understand now; the answer is no. Check here for some open source fhir client implementations that you could use as a baseline for your fhir client web app: https://wiki.hl7.org/Open_Source_FHIR_implementations